# how to use a recorder / player objects

Tags: java

I'm trying to put objects in a document. dat and then they can be read Does anyone know where is wrong?
The problem I have is that it is able to read the files you keep, I am not sure you save it, but if I find the file in the folders ...

I'm working with objets like:

```
public class Person {
    public int Id;
    public String Name;
    public boolean Show;

    public Persona(
            int identificator,
            String newName,
            boolean ShoworNot
            ){
        this.Id = identificator;
        this.Name = newName;
        this.Show = ShoworNot;
    }

Thanks
my code:

public void WriteFile
try {
            FileOutputStream file = new FileOutputStream("try.dat");
            ObjectOutputStream exit = new ObjectOutputStream(file);
            Iterator ite2 = people.iterator();
            while(ite2.hasNext()){
            Person person2 = (Person)ite2.next();
            exit.writeObject(person2);
            exit.close();
        }
            System.out.println("It's works");

        }
        catch (IOException e){
        System.out.println("Problems with the file.");
        }
}
  }
  }
  }
  public void ReadFile(){
      try {
FileInputStream file2 = new FileInputStream("try.dat");
ObjectInputStream entry = new ObjectInputStream(file2);
entry.readObject();
String data = (String)entry.readObject();
        entry.close();
System.out.println(data);
}

catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
System.out.println("It can't open the file document");
}
catch (IOException e) {
System.out.println("Problems with the file");
}
catch (Exception e) {
System.out.println("Error reading the file");
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your object must implement `Serializable` interface if you want to use `ObjectOutputStream`. Just change `public class Person {` to `public class Person implements Serializable {`

Also to see what is the problem, in each block `catch{}` write `e.printStackTrace()`

You have a mistake:

```
entry.readObject();
String data = (String)entry.readObject();
```

you are reading 1 object, ignoring it and trying to read second object, but you already read it, so you are at the end of file and you get EndOfFileException(EOF). remove first line. Second problem is the type of object is invalid. You writing an object `Person`, so you must read `Person`, not `String`:

```
Person data = (Person) entry.readObject();
```

Also after you send all data in file and before you close stream you must call `.flush()`

```
exit.writeObject(person2);
exit.flush();
exit.close();
```